# All curves emerging from a single origin point following up on Plexus effect

Tags: geometry-nodes, versions

I followed a couple of tutorials for creating a Plexus effect using Geo-nodes in Blender. But all my curves(connection) appear to come from a single point source and other dots do not connect at all. My node graph is exactly as followed from the tutorials, and yet it doesn't work.

Blender 4.0

[image: Failed attempt at creating Plexus effect, lines from one point only :(]

Links to the tutorials

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYgRdPR65o8&t
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj6ZZYO5qPY&t

Geo-node Screenshot

[image]

EDIT: The quick fix as pointed out by the user in the comment, The Point Cloud attribute had to connected to `Floored Modulo` Math node!

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? The GN screen capture is unreadable...

Comment: I've just done the tutorial and it works fine here so we'll need to see your Blend file as @StefLAncien says.

Comment: *"My node graph is exactly as followed from the tutorials"* - from my experience, when the problem isn't about something obviously hardware related (not the case here), this statement is never true :D. There are subtle things to look for, the colors of the sockets, a checkbox selected or not... It's very important to follow a tutorial using the same version of Blender, because sometimes a slight change of functionality between versions may change an important aspect of the setup. Avoid tutorials with αlpha versions, because you can't (easily) download the same version of Blender.

Comment: Hello all! @quellenform pointed out the mistake in my nodegraph, I had to plug in the Point cloud to 'Floored Modulo' math node! It is fixed now.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Haha you are right, I should have payed more attention to the concept to have figured this fix. Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to plug in the *Point Count* into the node `Floored Modulo`:

[image]

Comment: I keep feeling the method could be optimized more than either of the 2 examples, but haven't landed on it...

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, I agree, I would have solved it differently too, but I don't think that was the question.

Comment: @quellenform You are absolutely right! That fixed it! Thank you! As a blender hobbyist Geo-Nodes is by far the most frustrating thing ever. Awesome to see the result finally!!